# WSO2 IS 5.7.0 AuthenticationContext and UserOperationEventListener

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm developing an `UserOperationEventListener` to perform some operations after a federated user has been created using JIT in a local User Storage.

In the doPostAddUser method, I have to read the authentication context property `FrameworkConstants`.

`UNFILTERED_IDP_CLAIM_VALUES` because of some claims are filtered out by the DefaultClaimHandler and are not available in the *Map< String >, < String > claims* variable.

I know I could add claim mapping for the IdP but I prefer to manipulate those claims by code: how can I access the current AuthenticationContext in 
 `doPostAddUser` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to access AuthenticationContext in UserOperationEventListener and it is something we shouldn't do as per WSO2 Identity Server design architecture. If you want to modify claim handling logic by code, best way to achieve it is writing custom claim handler as per [1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Writing+a+Custom+Claim+Handler

Comment: Do you know if the <Extensions> element can have more than one ClaimHandler ? What is the execution order in case of more than one ? If the <Extensions> element can have just one ClaimHandler shall I have to extend the default one ?

Comment: You can have only one "ClaimHandler" element inside "Extensions". Yes you can extend DefaultClaimHandler https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/blob/master/components/authentication-framework/org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/application/authentication/framework/handler/claims/impl/DefaultClaimHandler.java

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is since you are using Identity Server 5.7.0, you can utilize adaptive authentication feature for claim transformation during JIT.

Have a look [1]

```
user.localClaims[“<local_claim_url>”] 

user.remoteClaims[“<remote_claim_url”]
```

Also you can get an idea from [2] about javascript configuration. If you prefer to write claim transformation logic from java use first option else this solution also works its up to you to decide based on your requirement.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Adaptive+Authentication+JS+API+Reference#AdaptiveAuthenticationJSAPIReference-userObject

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+User-Age-Based+Adaptive+Authentication